# TYPO3: check if current page is translated by typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript

For the generation of the canonical tag by typoscript, I need to check if the current page is translated. If not, the canonical needs to point to the url in default language.

How can I check if current page is translated by typoscript?

Language handling in my typoscript config:

```
sys_language_overlay = 1
sys_language_mode = content_fallback
```

Comment: I think you mix up two things here: the canonical is always the URL of the page you're currently visiting. So if you visit the translated version of a page, the canonical always has the URL of that specific translation. The other thing is hreflang to point to the translated versions of a page. If you use TYPO3 9.5 or newer, TYPO3 already creates these hreflang links for you.

Comment: Thank's Peter for your answer.
Sure, the canonical is the url of the current page.

Comment: In our case some pages are not translated yet and are shown in the default language instead. I.e.: https://www.klimaholzhaus.com/construction/zertifizierte-holzelemente/
We have domains for the pages in different languages (.com, .fr, .it, .ch). The problem is, that Google is showing results in different domains, because of the content fallback feature. Google should index the pages with the language corresponding to the domain. My idea is to set the canonical url in the default language/domain if there is no translation.

Comment: Now I get your problem, but I have no solution ready. I always avoid to use content_fallback. See it from the perspective of an English speaking visitor of your page: he has no use for German content because he won't understand it. So I think it's better to use strict mode and don't show not translated pages at all. This also helps with your duplicate content problem.

Comment: I'm totally with you, but my customer wants content fallback :(

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Then your customer has to live with the consequences. What you could maybe do is to create a userfunc which does the check for translated pages and generate the URL according to your needs. But this is a pretty messy solution.

Comment: Will probably result in that. Thank's for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested, I have worked out a solution to my task: Render the canonical url in default language if there is no translation for the current page (content_fallback)

```
page.headerData.10 = COA
page.headerData.10 {
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10.isPageTranslated.cObject = CONTENT
    10.isPageTranslated.cObject {
        table = pages
        select {
            selectFields = plo.sys_language_uid
            pidInList = {$config.rootPid}
            join = pages_language_overlay plo ON plo.pid = pages.uid            
            where = plo.pid = ###pid### AND plo.sys_language_uid = ###lang### AND plo.deleted = 0 AND plo.hidden = 0
            markers {
                pid.data = page:uid
                lang.data = page:sys_language_uid
            }
        }
        renderObj = TEXT
        # translation available
        renderObj {
            wrap = <link rel="canonical" href="|">
            typolink {
                parameter.data = TSFE:id
                returnLast = url
            }
            append = TEXT
            append.value (

)
        }
    }   
    20 = TEXT
    20 {
        data = register:isPageTranslated
        ifEmpty {
            # no translation available
            wrap = <link rel="canonical" href="|">
            typolink {
                parameter.data = TSFE:id
                additionalParams = &L=0
                returnLast = url
            }
            append = TEXT
            append.value (

)
        }
    }
}
```